# The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the net4bsl.bsl.co.uk scheme

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I get this error when trying to sync a team project on team foundation serer in visual studio 2017 at work

```
Git failed with a fatal error.

NotSupportedException encountered.

   The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the net4bsl.bsl.co.uk scheme.

cannot spawn /c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory

could not read Username for 'https://ams-british-steel.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

This is what I have configred as my proxy

```
git config --global http.proxy net4bsl.bsl.co.uk:8080
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You're not entering a valid URI scheme, such as `http://`. Try putting `http://` at the front of the proxy address.

Comment: Thanks but I get the same error even if I use `git config --global http.proxy http://net4bsl.bsl.co.uk:8080`

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765 on how to configure the proxy. And: Maybe the global config is "overwritten" with another (user or repo) config, check this too...

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have set the Windows environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY. If they are set, make sure the schema (http and https) is written there. If you modify that variables restart the terminal and try again.

I had the same issue and I solved it in that way.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, my environnement variables were screwing up the proxy, thus causing this error. I had to fix them.

Comment: I was having this problem and it turns out I had an HTTPS_PROXY environment variable set to "https://[my proxy url]". Changing that to "http://..." fixed the problem. HtH someone.